# How the maven know exactly the ${jsf.version} in pom.xml

Tags: maven, jsf, dependencies

In the `pom.xml` of our project, it define the dependencies for JSF as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.faces</groupId>
    <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
    <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My question is how/why Maven know exactly the version of JSF (in this case it get version 1.2) when we do not declare implicit JSF version?
Where do I can find we set the value of variable `${jsf.version}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's usually defined as a property in either the very same `pom.xml`, or in a parent `pom.xml`, or in user's own `settings.xml`, or in global `settings.xml`, or explicitly as command line argument.

In XML flavor, it look like this:

```xml
<properties>
    <jsf.version>1.2</jsf.version>
</properties>
```

In command line flavor, it look like this:

```
mvn -Djsf.version=1.2
```

#### See also:

- [Maven POM Reference - Properties](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Properties)